# Transpose data in SQL

Tags: sql

Can someone assist me on this?
As you can see from the first picture (Original data) I have date in format "Mar-12" and data for 2014,2015,2016 and 2017 year.
Now, I need to insert new column "year" where I need to put the year from Jan-14, Jan-15, Jan-16, Feb-16 etc.
Basically, I need some kind of data transpose, I think.
In the second picture "Final Order" I show in which order I need the data.

[image]

[image]

---

I don't know what is dbms.
So, this is how my data (original) looks like:

```
Customer|Section|Data|Jan-14|Feb-14|Jan-15|Feb-15

Total    Fore     SR   10     20     30      35
Total    Fore     TK   5       4     12      10
===================================================
```

And I need to put the data in this form:

```
Customer|Section|Data| Year |Jan|Feb|

Total     Fore    SR  2014   10   20
Total     Fore    TK  2014   5    4
Total     Fore    SR  2015   30   35
Total     Fore    TK  2015   12   10
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: My screen is too small. Simplify/minimize the problem.

Comment: *"I don't know what is dbms"* >> DBMS stands for Database Management System. In your case likely a Relational DBMS, seeing the tag "sql". For instance, SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL etc. Edit your question and supply a tag for the RDBMS you are working in.

Comment: Perhaps you aren't using a database and are only in Excel? If this is true, then please tag the question as "Excel" and remove the "SQL" tag.

Answer (score 0):

Given your sample of

```
create table t (Customer varchar(5),Section varchar(4), Data varchar(2), [Jan-14] int , [Feb-14] int, [Jan-15] int, [Feb-15] int)
insert into @t values
('Total' ,   'Fore' ,    'SR'  , 10 ,    20,     30,      35),
('Total' ,   'Fore' ,    'TK'  , 5  ,     4,     12,      10)
```

you can solve this if your sql dialect is ms sql server by unpivoting and then grouping by like so

```
select    customer,section,data,yyyy,
            sum(case when mm='Jan' then dts else 0 end) as 'Jan',
            sum(case when mm='Feb' then dts else 0 end) as 'Feb'
 from
(
select      customer,section,data,
            dummy,
            substring(dummy,1,3) as mm,
            concat('20',substring(dummy,5,2)) as yyyy,
            dts
from
(
select  customer,section,data,
        [Jan-14] , [Feb-14] , [Jan-15] , [Feb-15]
from t
) pvt
UNPIVOT
   (dts FOR dummy IN 
      ([Jan-14] , [Feb-14] , [Jan-15] , [Feb-15])
)AS unpvt
) x
 group by customer,section,yyyy,data
```

result

```
customer section data yyyy Jan         Feb
-------- ------- ---- ---- ----------- -----------
Total    Fore    SR   2014          10          20
Total    Fore    TK   2014           5           4
Total    Fore    SR   2015          30          35
Total    Fore    TK   2015          12          10
```

If your sql dialect does not have unpivot you can

```
select    customer,section,data,yyyy,
            sum(case when mm='Jan' then dts else 0 end) as 'Jan',
            sum(case when mm='Feb' then dts else 0 end) as 'Feb'
 from
( 
select   customer,section,data,2014 as yyyy,'Jan' as mm,[Jan-14] as dts from t
union all
select   customer,section,data,2014 as yyyy,'Feb' as mm,[Feb-14] as dts from t
union all
select   customer,section,data,2015 as yyyy,'Jan' as mm,[Jan-15] as dts from t
union all
select   customer,section,data,2015 as yyyy,'Feb' as mm,[Feb-15] as dts from t
)  x
 group by customer,section,yyyy,data
```

Clearly either method is a pain if you have an unknown/variable number/lots of columns in which case you would need write a script to generate a sql statement for submission to dynamic sql.